# ELB can't enable gzip on nginx server for node

Tags: node.js, nginx, gzip, amazon-elb, nginx-config

added the gzip configurations in nginx.conf but not showing `Content-Encoding: gzip` in dev tools, Is there any otherway to enable gzip?

```
 gzip on;
     gzip_http_version 1.1;
     gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
     gzip_min_length 256;
     gzip_vary on;
     gzip_proxied any;
     gzip_types application/atom+xml application/geo+json application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
 application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rdf+xml
 application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/wasm
 application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml
 application/xml font/eot font/otf font/ttf image/bmp image/svg+xml
 text/cache-manifest text/calendar text/css text/javascript
 text/markdown text/plain text/xml text/vcard
 text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component
 text/x-cross-domain-policy;
     gzip_buffers 16 8k;
     gzip_comp_level 6;
```

Comment: You need to show other config: location, server etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check location block. What your content-type is mapping to `gzip_types`.
2. Check if size is correctly.

You can use `curl` to check.

```
curl localhost -I --compressed
curl localhost -I
```

```
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 65229
```